# Issue with editing JQuery document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code does not run as written. If the button click part (the 3 lines after the first alert) is removed it works fine. It seems like any edits made to the JS/JQ area lead to issues. What could be going wrong here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Problem #2</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Problem #2:</h1>

        <form>
            <input type="number" placeholder="Enter your cents" min="0" />
            <input type="button" name="Solve" value="Solve" />
        </form>
        <div id="answer">
            <div id="quarters"></div>
            <div id="dimes"></div>
            <div id="nickels"></div>
            <div id="pennies"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                alert("Handler for .ready() called.");
                $('button').click(function{
                    alert("Hello World");
                });
            });

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have no button tags to be clicked. Wrong jQuery selector

Comment: You have syntax error in that part...

Comment: You're looking for input[type=button]

Comment: The error occurs even if I use answer in place of button.

Comment: You cannot simply use `'answers'` in place of `'button'`.  I think you should study how to use [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has a syntax error:

```
$('button').click(function{
      alert("Hello World");
});
```

and needs to be this (missing parens):

```
$('button').click(function () {
      alert("Hello World");
});
```

In the future, you should look at the debug console and it will tell you what line your syntax errors are on and often give you an idea what the error is.  You can also run your code through [jsHint](http://www.jshint.com/) (just paste in the relevant code) and it will often give you details on where syntax is wrong or suspect.

---

In addition, since you don't have any `<button>` tags in your HTML, your selector is also probably wrong.  If you're targeting the solve button, then you should probably change your HTML like this:

```
<input id="solve" type="button" name="Solve" value="Solve" />
```

and your HTML like this:

```
$('#solve').click(function () {
      alert("Hello World");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the parenthesis after `function` in the third line of your script.

Also, as @ArtOfCode in the comments said, your selector should be `input[type=button]`.

It should look like this:

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function () {
```

Comment: Thanks. I really feel like a n00b right now.

Now to figure out how to make the alert come up when the button is clicked.....

Comment: @mikeandike Based on your code it seems it should do that...what is happening exactly?